# Efficient way to shift values in one matrix according to the values in another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I want to shift the values in `matrix_a` according to the values in `matrix_b`. So if the value in `matrix_b` at postion `0,0` is `1`, then the element in the `result_matrix` at `0,0` should be the element that is at `1,1` in `matrix_a`. I already have this working using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

matrix_a = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3],
                      [4, 5, 6],
                      [7, 8, 9]])
matrix_b = np.matrix([[1, 1, 0],
                      [0,-1, 0],
                      [0, 0, -1]])
result_matrix = np.zeros((3,3))


for x in range(matrix_b.shape[0]):
  for y in range(matrix_b.shape[1]):
    value = matrix_b.item(x,y)
    result_matrix[x][y]=matrix_a.item(x+value,y+value)

print(result_matrix)
```

which results in:

```
[[5. 6. 3.]
 [4. 1. 6.]
 [7. 8. 5.]]
```

Right now this is quite slow on large matrices, and I have the feeling that this can be optimized using one of numpy or scipy's functions. Can someone tell me how this can be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.indices`

```
ix = np.indices(matrix_a.shape)
matrix_a[tuple(ix + np.array(matrix_b))]
Out[]: 
matrix([[5, 6, 3],
        [4, 1, 6],
        [7, 8, 5]])
```

As a word of advice, try to avoid using `np.matrix` - it's only really for compatibility with old `MATLAB` code, and breaks a lot of `numpy` functions.  `np.array` works just as well 99% of the time, and the rest of the time `np.matrix` will be confusing for core `numpy` users.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way with [`integer-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) generated off the same iterators as open ranged arrays to get row, column indices for all elements -

```
I,J = np.ogrid[:matrix_b.shape[0],:matrix_b.shape[1]]
out = matrix_a[I+matrix_b, J+matrix_b]
```

Output for given sample -

```
In [152]: out
Out[152]: 
matrix([[5, 6, 3],
        [4, 1, 6],
        [7, 8, 5]])
```

Timings on a large dataset `5000x5000` -

```
In [142]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: N = 5000 # matrix size
     ...: matrix_a = np.random.rand(N,N)
     ...: matrix_b = np.random.randint(0,N,matrix_a.shape)-matrix_a.shape[1]

# @Daniel F's soln
In [143]: %%timeit
     ...: ix = np.indices(matrix_a.shape)
     ...: matrix_a[tuple(ix + np.array(matrix_b))]
1.37 s ± 99.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Solution from this post
In [149]: %%timeit
     ...: I,J = np.ogrid[:matrix_b.shape[0],:matrix_b.shape[1]]
     ...: out = matrix_a[I+matrix_b, J+matrix_b]
1.17 s ± 3.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Strange that mine takes longer despite using broadcasting, and with a large `std`.  Maybe something getting cached?  Or just the `np.matrix` conversion to `np.array`?

Comment: @DanielF Think it's the explicit use of `np.indices`. Also, the tuple conversion probably. I am using arrays for benchmarking.